# SQL Query User has one record in the table but not another one

Tags: sql

I have a table with Employee Type Codes and I am trying to return all the Users that do not have a specific LeaveType

example:

```
EmployeeNO LeaveType
---------------------    
1111       Personal
1111       Vacation
1111       Sick Bank
2222       Personal
2222       Vacation
3333       Personal
3333       Vacation
```

So I want to query all users and return a list of those in the `Sick Bank` and ones that are not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Getting employees for a particular leave type is strait forward

```
select employeeNO from table1 where leaveType = 'Sick Bank'
```

If an employee has more than one leave type then a query with <> could return multiple rows for an employee even if they do have a 'Sick Bank' row.

```
select employeeNO from table1 
where employeeNo not in (select employeeNO from table1 where leaveType = 'Sick Bank')
```

Comment: I assume this will be a relatively large table, and as such using a where Not in would be, where N is the number of rows, (N * N) - N compares.

Comment: That listed me all the employees that did not have a Sick Bank Code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get Sick Banks

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE leaveType = 'Sick Bank'
```

To get Non Sick Banks

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE leaveType <> 'Sick Bank'
```

Comment: The non Sick Bank query will incorrectly return user 1111 twice even though it has a Sick Bank row.

Comment: I imagine this table has days that the employee is off, and as such, the employee should be returned more than once despite being there twice.

Comment: but if the point was to only pull distinct rows, he could use SELECT DISTINCT