# Get count of ID for name-value pair when name doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

In mysql - table like this:

```
ID   Name    Value

1    Color   Blue
1    Weight  50
1    Type    Fruit
2    Color   Red
2    Weight  40
3    Color   Yellow
```

I want to get a count of distinct ID's that have a name/characteristic of 'Type' and a distinct count of ID's that don't.  The first one (those that do) is easy since it's defined, but if I do a select count(distinct ID) where name <> 'type' - ID 1 will still be part of that count as it has other rows/attributes that <> 'type'.

In this example - the desired result for distinct count = 'type' would be 1 (ID 1) and for distinct count <> 'type' would be 2 (ID's 2 & 3).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want both counts, why not simply subtract the number of groups with the `Type` characteristic from the total number of groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [SQL Query User has one record in the table but not another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896462/sql-query-user-has-one-record-in-the-table-but-not-another-one/18896706#18896706)

You can select where the id is not in a subquery looking for ids that have type

```
select count(id) from table where id not in (select id from table where name = 'type')
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id HAVING 
CONCAT(",",CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(name), ","))
NOT LIKE '%,Type,%'
```

will give you all ids without `Type`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30837/1

(Concat with `,` ensures, that you are not matching `XType` by accident.)

while

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids 
FROM(SELECT id, count(name) as count FROM test 
GROUP BY id HAVING CONCAT(",",CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(name), ","))
NOT LIKE '%,Type,%') as temp;
```

will give you the desired count: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30837/9

Answer (score 0):

for this particular task you can use:

```
select count(distinct ID) from table
where ID in (select ID from table where name='type') --- this will give you count of IDs where type exists

select count(distinct ID) from table
where ID not in (select ID from table where name='type') -- this will give you count of IDs without type
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN Name='Type' THEN 'Type'
          ELSE 'Non-Type'
       END Name
      ,ID
      ,COUNT(ID)
FROM Stuff
GROUP BY
     CASE
          WHEN Name='Type' THEN 'Type'
          ELSE 'Non-Type'
     END 
    ,ID
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d14b/2)